# What does "print >>" do in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have to translate a code from python 2 into python 3 and I can't understand what does `print >>` do and how should I write it in python 3.

```
print >> sys.stderr, '--'
print >> sys.stderr, 'entrada1: ', entrada1
print >> sys.stderr, 'entrada2: ', entrada2
print >> sys.stderr, '--'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `>> sys.stderr` part makes the `print` statement output to stderr instead of stdout in Python 2.

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) also has an extended form, defined by the second portion of the
>   syntax described above. This form is sometimes referred to as “print
>   chevron.” In this form, the first expression after the `>>` must
>   evaluate to a “file-like” object, specifically an object that has a
>   `write()` method as described above. With this extended form, the
>   subsequent expressions are printed to this file object. If the first
>   expression evaluates to `None`, then `sys.stdout` is used as the file for
>   output.

In Python 3 use the `file` argument to the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print) function:

```
 print("spam", file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 23):

To convert these from Python 2 to Python 3, change:

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'Hello'
```

to:

```
print('Hello', file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 4):

For printing to `stderr` note

```
sys.stderr.write()
```

is portable across versions, yet you need to add a newline, unlike `print`; for instance

```
import sys

errlog = sys.stderr.write
errlog("an error message\n")
```

Comment: Also note that [`.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) expects its argument to be a string. To write something other than a string, it needs to be converted to a string first: `sys.stderr.write(str(['the answer', 42]))`