# What does >> do if it is neither bitwise operation nor print chevron?

Tags: python, syntax, arguments, operators

Is there anyone who could help figure out what the double greater-than symbol (i.e. `Drug >> float` in line 10 and `Drug >> int` in line 13) means in the following python scripts?

```
 1  from owlready2 import *
 2
 3  onto = get_ontology("http://test.org/onto.owl")
 4
 5  with onto:
 6      class Drug(Thing):
 7          def get_per_tablet_cost(self):
 8              return self.cost / self.number_of_tablets
 9
10      class has_for_cost(Drug >> float, FunctionalProperty):
11          python_name = "cost"
12
13      class has_for_number_of_tablets(Drug >> int, FunctionalProperty):
14          python_name = "number_of_tablets"
15
16  my_drug = Drug(cost = 10.0, number_of_tablets = 5)
17  print(my_drug.get_per_tablet_cost())

--- Below is the printing outcome. ---
2.0
```

The code is copied from [here](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mixing_python_owl.html#adding-python-methods-to-an-owl-class) and runs in python 3.

The `>>` symbol here is not bitwise operator. [Python's bitwise operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types), say `x >> y`, requires `y` to be an integer. It is clear that the code here (`Drug >> float`) is not shifting `Drug` right by `float` bits.

Although similar questions were asked before (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832615/what-do-and-mean-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385674/what-does-print-do-in-python)), their answers mostly pointed to the so-called ["print chevron"](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) in python 2, where the `>>` redirects the to-be-printed messages to the file-like object specified right after the `>>`. They do not apply to my question because here is not a case of print statement.

To trace the `>>` in the code above, I revised the script in line 10 as `class has_for_cost(Drug >> list, FunctionalProperty)` (namely replace `>> float` with `>> list`) and ran the code again. It raised an AttributeError as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1be374b27b04> in <module>()
      8             return self.cost / self.number_of_tablets
      9 
---> 10     class has_for_cost(Drug >> list, FunctionalProperty):
     11         python_name = "cost"
     12 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/prop.py in __init__(Prop, name, bases, obj_dict)
    254 class ReasoningPropertyClass(PropertyClass):
    255   def __init__(Prop, name, bases, obj_dict):
--> 256     super().__init__(name, bases, obj_dict)
    257 
    258     if (not Prop.namespace.world is owl_world):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/prop.py in __init__(Prop, name, bases, obj_dict)
     78 
     79       if not range is False:
---> 80         Prop.range.extend(range)
     81 
     82       if not inverse_property is False:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/util.py in extend(self, l)
     58   def append(self, x):          old = list(self); super().append(x)         ; self._callback(self._obj, old)
     59   def insert(self, i, x):       old = list(self); super().insert(i, x)      ; self._callback(self._obj, old)
---> 60   def extend(self, l):          old = list(self); super().extend(l)         ; self._callback(self._obj, old)
     61   def remove(self, x):          old = list(self); super().remove(x)         ; self._callback(self._obj, old)
     62   def __delitem__(self, i):     old = list(self); super().__delitem__(i)    ; self._callback(self._obj, old)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/owlready2/prop.py in _range_changed(Prop, old)
    143     for x in new - old:
    144       if isinstance(x, ClassConstruct): x._set_ontology(Prop.namespace.ontology)
--> 145       x2 = _universal_datatype_2_abbrev.get(x) or x.storid
    146       Prop.namespace.ontology.add_triple(Prop.storid, rdf_range, x2)
    147 

AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'storid'
```

With the traceback info, though, I still could not find the answer. I would be very thankful if anyone could help figure out what the `>>` does in the code.

Comment: Classes can implement the bitshift operator however they choose, some less intuitively than others.  The magic method you should be looking for in the class definition is `__rshift__(self, other)`, `__rrshift__(self, other)`, or `__irshift__(self, other)`

Comment: @jedwards is right. It is `__rshift__()`  defined in a base object, `ThingClass`, do the trick. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51184773/10033543).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Drug >> float` calls `Drug`'s [`__rshift__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rshift__) method. That method can do whatever it wants; it doesn't have to be a binary shift operation.

Reading [the owlready2 documentation](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/properties.html) reveals that `domain >> range` is a fancy way of creating an `ObjectProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

[Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181373/10033543) has answered the question in brief. Below is just to save time for those who don't want to download and parse the source codes of [owlready2](https://bitbucket.org/jibalamy/owlready2/src) but still want to trace how it works in the actual codes.

1. `Drug` is an object created on the basis of another object `ThingClass`, as defined in /owlready2/entity.py.
2. `Drug >> float` calls `Drug.__rshift__(self, float)` [[explained](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rshift__)].
3. It is not `Drug` but its base object `ThingClass` that has a `__rshift__` method, which reads in the entity.py:

   ```
   class ThingClass(EntityClass):
       ...
       def __rshift__(Domain, Range):
           import owlready2.prop
           owlready2.prop._next_domain_range = (Domain, Range)
           if isinstance(Range, ThingClass) or isinstance(Range, ClassConstruct):
               return owlready2.prop.ObjectProperty
           else:
               return owlready2.prop.DataProperty
   ```
4. `Drug >> float` is equivalent to `__rshift__(Domain=Drug, Range=float)`, which is in fact ***not*** doing a binary arithmetic operation but returns/creates either a DataProperty or an ObjectProperty, depending on the type of Range.